# Show time left, warn before automatic hangup

Tags: usability, gui-design, windows-os, timeout

I'm working on a Windows desktop application where the user deals with incoming calls by emergency devices. Because the inbound capacity is limited, the connections should be kept short, a time-out gets working if the user doesn't interact. I'm trying to make sure the limitation is understood by users without disturbing them.

Currently, I use an inverted progress bar in upright position getting a *glass-half-full* look.

[image] (Text: working mode held for the 27 seconds to come)

**Is there something wrong with this approach from a (professional) UX perspective?**

I've also an additional question because the time-out period differs with modes and devices, ranging from 50 seconds to 9 minutes.

**Should I deliver actual time-out values to the user?**
Or better start displaying the "regress-bar" 50 seconds before hangup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it as such. It is a little bit non-standard to have a vertical bar like that, a bit of a break in standard functionality consistency, but nothing to cause anyone who thinks about it for a few seconds any trouble.

There could be a slight problem in using a 'loading bar' when it actually means the opposite of loading- when it is full the system will be 'unloaded'. But again I don't forsee this causing many problems. People are used to time outs from windows.

Best IMO would be to give the actual total time they have (with a handy link to an explanation why) and how much of that time they have remaining. And something graphical like your loading bar to show this at a glance.